# Plot the probability density function in a way that the output can be a smooth curve

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, kernel-density, probability-density

I am trying to plot the pdf of a dataset in a way that the pdf appears as a smooth curve.
For that, I was using seaborn.kdeplot. The problem with this is - the dataset has a strict range, and the KDE plot tends to cross the range at both edges. To limit the pdf curve within the range I tried to use the **clip** parameter, but it makes the edges abrupt, not a smooth starting and ending. The abrupt changes at the ends do not look good visually, therefore, I am looking for other ways to plot the pdf.

Could you please provide some insights on this issue? Is there any other way that I can plot the pdf?

As an example, pls find the following code:

```
data = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
sns.kdeplot(data)
sns.kdeplot(data, clip=(0, 1))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the data really ends abrupt, a smooth ending would falsify the visualization.  Anyway, a kdeplot is only meant for data that ends and starts smooth, as the kde is the sum of many small gaussian bell curves.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the comment. Could you pls suggest any other way to plot the pdf of data that has a range, similar to the uniform distribution.

Comment: An alternative to a kdeplot could be a stepplot: `ax = sns.histplot(..., element='step', fill=False)` with `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)`.